# Data not displaying in on load - only after page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm new to React JS, and I've been working through a few tutorials to get my head around it.

The following code was taken from a tutorial on which comments are now closed, and I'm trying to resolve a problem with it.

When I run the app, the data from Firebase doesn't display, and I also can't add items to the list - nothing appears to happen for the user, although I can see the data being added in Firebase. If I reload the page, everything works fine.

I'm guessing this is something to do with componentDidMount, which I understand is only called on the first load of the page, so if the user isn't logged in, the data isn't loaded, and won't be, even after the user logs in - is that right?

Could anyone help me load the data as soon as the user logs in, rather than requiring a refresh of the page?

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import firebase, { auth, provider } from './firebase.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentItem: '',
      username: '',
      datetime: '',
      items: [],
      user: null,
      profileImg: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }
  login() {
      auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
          .then((result) => {
              const user = result.user;
              this.setState({
                  user
              });
          });

  }
  logout() {
      auth.signOut()
          .then(() => {
              this.setState({
                  user: null
              });
          });
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('items');
    const item = {
        title: this.state.currentItem,
        user: this.state.user.displayName || this.state.user.email,
        profileImg: this.state.user.photoURL
    }
    itemsRef.push(item);
    this.setState({
      currentItem: '',
      username: '',
      profileImg: this.state.user.photoURL
    });
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('items');

    itemsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      let items = snapshot.val();
      let newState = [];
      for (let item in items) {
        newState.push({
          id: item,
          title: items[item].title,
          user: items[item].user,
          profileImg: items[item].profileImg
        });
      }
      this.setState({
        items: newState
      });
    });

    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            this.setState({ user });
        }
    });
  }

  removeItem(itemId) {
    const itemRef = firebase.database().ref(`/items/${itemId}`);
    itemRef.remove();
  }
  render() {
      return (
          <div className='app'>
            <header>
              <div className="wrapper">
                <h1></h1>
                  {this.state.user ?
                      <button onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button>
                      :
                      <button onClick={this.login}>Log In</button>
                  }
              </div>
            </header>

              {this.state.user ?
                  <div>
                    <div className='user-profile'>
                      <img src={this.state.user.photoURL} alt={this.state.user.displayName} />
                    </div>
                    <div className='container'>
                        <section className='display-item'>
                            <div className="wrapper">
                                <ul>
                                    {this.state.items.reverse().map((item) => {
                                        return (
                                            <li key={item.id}>
                                                <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                                                <p>brought by: {item.user}
                                                    {item.user === this.state.user.displayName || item.user === this.state.user.email ?
                                                        <button onClick={() => this.removeItem(item.id)}>Remove Item</button> : null}

                                                    <img src={item.profileImg} alt={this.state.user.displayName} className={"profileImg"} />

                                                </p>
                                            </li>
                                        )
                                    })}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                      <section className='add-item'>
                        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="What's your name?" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.user.displayName || this.state.user.email} disabled />
                          <input type="text" name="currentItem" placeholder="What are you bringing?" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.currentItem} />
                          <button>Add Item</button>
                        </form>
                      </section>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  :
                  <div className='wrapper'>
                    <p>You must be logged in to see this page.</p>
                  </div>
              }

          </div>

      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Then is firebase.js I have:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
export const auth = firebase.auth();

export default firebase;
```

I'm fairly certain that this issue exists in the original tutorial, which can be viewed at https://css-tricks.com/firebase-react-part-2-user-authentication/.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

John.

Comment: What do you have in `./firabe.js`? could you please publish it?

Comment: I've added it in, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just pull your firebase call out into a separate function, and call it after the user has logged in?:

```
login() {
  auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((result) => {
          this.callFirebaseFunction()
          const user = result.user;
          this.setState({
              user
          });
      });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should use an observer to keep track of the user's sign-in status. That is **onAuthStateChanged**. So code would be,if user is signed in, and not equals to null then retrive data. Your code should be:

```js
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

Follow official documentation for perfect results: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users